# ¿Cuál sería la expresión regular para impedir más de un espacio en blanco?

Tags: php

Tengo un campo de formulario donde va el nombre y apellido, y obviamente necesito que solo se puedan ingresar letras en mayusculas y minusculas y que no sea valido mas de un espacio en blanco, y nada de caracteres extraños. Por ejemplo esto seria valido: EDUARDO alcoverro Vasco. Necesito hacer este filtro para que no manden inputs con solo espacios en blanco. Estoy intentando aprender expresiones regulares pero es muy complicado. Si alguien sabe de un generador de expresiones regulares que sea sencillo, que lo ponga en los comentarios por favor.

Comment: Lo de pedir solo un espacio en blanco no es aconsejable porque existen apellidos compuestos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si el usuario ingresó dos o más espacio en blanco seguramente se equivoco, podes ahorrarle tiempo y quitarlos por programación con algo así

```
$Nombre = preg_replace("/\s+/", " ", trim($Nombre));
```

Donde "\s" machea espacios y "+" obliga a que se repita una o más veces.

y después validar que el valor solo tenga letras y espacios

```
if (!preg_match("/^([a-z\s]+)$/i", $Nombre)) {
    // Mensaje de error
}
```

y si quieres permitir nombres con acentos y Ñ

```
if (!preg_match("/^([a-z\sáéíóúñÁÉÍÓÚÑ]+)$/i", $Nombre)) {
    // Mensaje de error
}
```

Comment: Explicame por favor para que sirve el signo " ^ "....Lo otro lo entiendo más o menos

Comment: y el simbolo "$" tampoco lo entiendo

Comment: El símbolo **^** al inicio y el ** $ ** al final, indican que el texto debe iniciar y terminar con la expresión. 

Por ej: si no incluis **^**, el texto "123 JUAN" pasaría la validación. Lo mismo si sacas el **$**, el texto nombre "JUAN 999" pasaría la prueba.

Comment: Pero el problema que tengo es que no solo me acepta letras y numeros sino tambien cualquier caracter extraño, por ejemplo %, > = **....y yo no quiero que valide esos. Ademas si doy muchos espacios en blanco tambien van a aparecer.

Comment: En caso **preg_match("/^([a-z\s]+)$/i", $Nombre)** valida caracteres como "%", ">" o "=". Es muy raro lo que planteas. Mirá el ejemplo http://ideone.com/OSf4h8

Comment: Pero entonces no existe una forma de evitar esos caracteres "% > *" con expresiones regulares??? No me parece raro solo querer que la gente ingrese letras, numeros y guiones, nada de caracteres extraños o ajenos a eso

Comment: Se me olvidó un "que" y un ? en el comentario anterior, quise poner **¿En que casos esa funciona te devuelve que es válido un texto que contenga caracteres especiales?**. Lo que dice ese regex es que solo permita letras de la A a la Z y espacios. 
Después te dejé un link a un código de ejemplo del código, lo pudiste ver? Lo escribí en PHP ya que tu pregunta sólo tenia el tag "php".

Si lo que necesitas es que no se puedan escribir caracteres especiales en el input HTML necesitas usar javascript.